# Would it be possible to access to GPU-RAM from CPU-Cores by simple pointer in a new CUDA6?

Tags: cuda, gpgpu, nvidia, virtual-address-space

Now, if I use this code to try access to GPU-RAM from CPU-Cores by using CUDA5.5 in GeForce GTX460SE (CC2.1), then I get an exception "Access Violation":

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    unsigned char* gpu_ptr = NULL;
    cudaMalloc((void **)&gpu_ptr, 1024*1024);

    *gpu_ptr = 1;

    int q; std::cin >> q;
    return 0;
}
```

But we know, that there is UVA(Unified Virtual Addressing). And there are some new:

- 25 October 2013 - 331.17 Beta Linux GPU Driver: The new NVIDIA Unified Kernel Memory module is a new kernel module for a Unified Memory feature to be exposed by an upcoming release of NVIDIA's CUDA. The new module is nvidia-uvm.ko and will allow for a unified memory space between the GPU and system RAM. http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTQ5NDc
- Key features of CUDA 6 include: Unified Memory -- Simplifies programming by enabling applications to access CPU and GPU memory without the need to manually copy data from one to the other, and makes it easier to add support for GPU acceleration in a wide range of programming languages. http://www.techpowerup.com/194505/nvidia-dramatically-simplifies-parallel-programming-with-cuda-6.html

Would it be possible to access memory GPU-RAM from CPU-Cores by using the simple pointer  in a new CUDA6?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, the new `unified memory` feature in CUDA 6 will make it possible, *on Kepler devices and beyond* (so not on your Fermi GPU) to share pointers between host and device code.

In order to accomplish this, you will need to use a Kepler device (so cc 3.0 or 3.5) and the new `cudaMallocManaged` API.  This will be further documented when CUDA 6.0 is officially available, but in the meantime you can read more about it at [this blog](http://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/unified-memory-in-cuda-6/), which includes examples.

This mechanism does not magically cause the effects of the PCI Express bus to disappear, so in effect what is happening is that two copies of the data are being made "behind the scenes" and `cudaMemcpy` operations are scheduled automatically by the cuda runtime, as needed. There are a variety of other implementation issues to be aware of, for now I would suggest reading the blog.

Note that Unified Memory (UM) is distinct from Unified Virtual Addressing (UVA) which has been available since CUDA 4.0 and is [documented](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#unified-virtual-address-space).

Comment: Thank you! That is, opportunities to access from CPU-Core directly to the GPU-RAM still will not. But will be possible, allocate a managed-memory, which automatically at the page level will move from the CPU-RAM to GPU-RAM and back, depending on how the driver is deemed to more optimal performance. And if managed-memory moved to GPU-RAM, and then CPU-Core try to access to it, then CPU will initiate DMA-controller to send data to this GPU-RAM(memory page). Is that right?

Comment: From the programmer's perspective, the CPU "appears" to be able to directly access the GPU memory (if it was allocated with `cudaMallocManaged`).  The rest of your statements appear correct to me.

Comment: I.e. if I use SSE-instructions to access from CPU-Core to GPU-RAM, then data will be send into PCI-Express BAR(Base Address Registers - as hardware feature http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_Address_Register#Bus_enumeration ), in which mapped GPU-RAM, and the important thing - DMA-controller for it will not be used (because the DMA-controller adds latency for small packets), isn't it?

Comment: I'm not going to go into the details of the implementation of this feature, which isn't public.  But if you use a pointer allocated with `cudaMallocManaged`, and obey the other requirements (such as don't access it while a kernel that also accesses it is running), then it should "just work" whether your code uses SSE or not.

Comment: Ok. I am interesting only performance on which affect, if DMA-controller work or not.